# How to attach click events with object parameters with xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a list of stackLayouts and i want to know which stackLayout was clicked.

PFB the code using which i'm trying to create a stackLayout,

```
foreach(var package in profileEmailAddressViewModel.Employee.Packages)
        {
            var stackLayoutEmail = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
            };

                var labelEmployerEmail = new Label
                {
                    FontSize = 17,
                    TextColor = Color.FromHex("#030303"),
                    Margin = new Thickness(15, 12, 0, 12),
                    HeightRequest = 20,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                };

                labelEmployerEmail.Text = package.WorkEmailAddress;

                var imageListItem = new Image
                {
                    Source = "arrow.png",
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 15, 0),
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                    HeightRequest = 16,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                };

                stackLayoutEmail.Children.Add(labelEmployerEmail);
                stackLayoutEmail.Children.Add(imageListItem);

                var tapUpdateEmailEvent = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                tapUpdateEmailEvent.Tapped += (s, e) => {
                    // How to pass in the package parameter value with tapped event here?
                };

                stackLayoutEmail.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapUpdateEmailEvent);


            AddressLayout.Children.Add(stackLayoutEmail);

        }
```

How to pass in the package parameter value with tapped event here?

Please let me know what is the way to attach the parameter when running a for loop to create a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `CommandParameter` on the `TapGestureRecognizer`

Note:

This should be ideally handled using a `ListView`. Just set the `ItemsSource` to the `Packages`

If you are gonna stick with this method, create only **one** `TapGestureRecognizer` preferably in constructor and add it to all the StackLayout's gestures